# twitter-bootstrap-wizard bug switching step just by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to do a wizard like
[THIS](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-finishbutton.html)
, I implemented it easily, it almost works but a weird bug stopped me to continue.
In fact, when you are on the first step, "First" is kind of active/highlighted, but for me when I just scroll, it passes from First to Third without changing the content witch is different. and continuously switch from third to second tab just by scrolling slowly. I don't know why... I tried a lot of different implementations and on different browsers but the same bug appears.
Please someone had the same issue x)

Comment: Please keep answers out of the question. I have moved your answer to the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was because I used the navbar class for it and it was used to for the upside menu and when scrolling down the navbar's menu was switching style and the navbar used for the wizard was switching style too (obvious) so I just had to unput the navbar class for the wizard. I dunno if I'm understandable but I least I tried :)

<sub>Note: this was extracted from the question and posted on behalf of the OP</sub>